# canvas.drawImage change focus point to center

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using Custom Painter to draw an image of a dot onto another image. The current result is that the image is being drawn with the top-left being the focus point, i.e. when I click, the mouse pointer is focused on the top-left of the image. I wish for this focus to be on the center. How does one go about changing the focus point to the center of the image? My assumption is that you need to manipulate the offset somehow, but I haven't found a tutorial that explains how to go about it. gif below shows what it currently looks like:

[image]

Current code:

```
class MyCustomPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Offset offset;
  ui.Image image;

  MyCustomPainter({this.offset, this.image});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    if (offset == null) return;
    canvas.drawImage(image, offset, Paint());
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(MyCustomPainter other) => other.offset != offset;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution pretty quickly, but I've decided to keep the question up with my own answer in case this helps someone else.

My assumption was correct in changing the offset, but the idea is to create a new `Offset` object and offset the original X and Y coordinates by half the image width and half the image height.

```
class MyCustomPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Offset offset;
  ui.Image image;

  MyCustomPainter({this.offset, this.image});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    if (offset == null) return;
    Offset offsetNew =
        new Offset(offset.dx - image.width / 2, offset.dy - image.height / 2);

    canvas.drawImage(image, offsetNew, Paint());
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(MyCustomPainter other) => other.offset != offset;
}
```

Result below:

[image]